# Can you suppress the echoing of executed commands in a CMD for loop?

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line

I try to run a for loop in the Windows 10 cmd shell without producing any output at all.
The corresponding command looks like this:

```
for /R SOMEPATH %f in (*.*) do copy /Y %f ANOTHERPATH >nul 2>&1
```

While it was possible to silence the `copy` command with the redirects, there is still an output for every file copied. An example, where 3 files are copied looks like this:

```
C:\> for /R SOMEPATH %f in (*.*) do copy /Y %f ANOTHERPATH >nul 2>&1
C:\> copy /Y %f ANOTHERPATH >nul 2>&1                    #this is unwanted
C:\> copy /Y %f ANOTHERPATH >nul 2>&1                    #this is unwanted
C:\> copy /Y %f ANOTHERPATH >nul 2>&1                    #this is unwanted
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, put `@` left to command `copy`, i.e. use `for /R SOMEPATH %f in (*.*) do @copy /Y %f ANOTHERPATH >nul 2>&1`. It would be also possible to start `cmd` with option `/Q` to turn off command echoing, i.e. use the quiet mode of Windows command processor.

Comment: One other way is to use the command `ECHO OFF` which will remain in effect until `ECHO ON` is used.

Comment: Redirecting stdout and stderr to NULL will also omit any messages if the command should fail. Is that ok for your process?

Comment: `@(for /R SOMEPATH %f in (*.*) do copy /Y %f ANOTHERPATH)>nul 2>&1`